# How to get data in resource file?

Tags: c++

I get the NULL(hRsrc) when it is running.

.cpp

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_EXE1), _T("EXE"));

if (hRsrc == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("LoadEmbedded"), TEXT("1"), MB_OK);
}

HANDLE hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hRsrc);
if (hRes == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("LoadEmbedded"), TEXT("2"), MB_OK);
}

LPSTR lpRes = (LPSTR)LockResource(hRes);
if (lpRes == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("LoadEmbedded"), TEXT("3"), MB_OK);
}
```

.rc

```
IDR_EXE1                EXE                     "crashpad_handler.exe"
```

I set the data id and type.

resource.h

```
#define IDR_EXE1                        105
```

Comment: The .exe file is in the resource file.

Comment: And I failed this command in admin cmd.
: rc.exe /fo "mydir/myfile.res" "mydir/myfile.rc"

Is it related this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `.rc` file have an `#include "resource.h"` statement?

If not, then the `IDR_EXE1` macro won't be defined when the `.rc` is compiled, and thus the resource's ID will be the literal string `"IDR_EXE1"` and not the numeric `105` (use a resource viewer tool to verify that). In which case, you would have to use `_T("IDR_EXE1")` instead of `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_EXE1)` when calling `FindResource()`:

```cpp
HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDR_EXE1"), _T("EXE"));
```

Otherwise, fix the `.rc` file:

```rc
#include "resource.h" // <-- add this!

IDR_EXE1                EXE                     "crashpad_handler.exe"
```

Comment: The .rc file have an #include "resource.h" statement.

Comment: I add it and had run but hRsrc is NULL. And i fixed HRSRC.

Comment: Platform Toolset is Visual Studio 2010 (v100).

Comment: And It's happening in dllmain.